# Setting styles to a custom component inside navigationOption in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to set styling for a custom component, inside navigationOptions in react native. But the stying doesnt work and it give an error saying. Same styling is working in another text box of the same screen.

P:S: I could achieve this by doing this? Am I doing this correct? Is this the proper way of handling this?

```
class WorkoutScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchText: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      searchWorkouts: this.searchWorkoutHandler,
      onChangeSearchText: this.onChangeSearchTextHandler,
      searchText: this.state.searchText
    });
  }

  // on change search text
  onChangeSearchTextHandler = value => {
    this.setState({
      searchText: value
    });
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      searchText: value
    });
  };

  // search workouts
  searchWorkoutHandler = () => {
    alert("Searching Workouts");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Im Here</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;

    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <SearchInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value={params.searchText}
          source={Search}
          borderRadius={50}
          placeholder="Search / Filter"
          onChangeText={value => params.onChangeSearchText(value)}
          onPress={() => params.searchWorkouts()}
        />
      ),
      headerTitleStyle: { width: "100%", alignItems: "center" },
      headerStyle: {
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <ClickableIcon
          source={Bookmark}
          onIconPressed={() => alert("Notifications Clicked Workout")}
        />
      ),
      headerRight: (
        <ClickableIcon
          source={Movements}
          onIconPressed={() => alert("Add New Clicked")}
        />
      )
    };
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
  },
  searchInput: {
    height: 45,
    color: "gray",
    fontSize: 18
  }
});

export default WorkoutScreen;
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: What error are you getting?. Post your error msg.

Comment: You need to add the code for your `SearchInput` component and post the error message.

Comment: Guys, I fixed it by doing this. I have put my code here in the post. I want to know, if this is the best way to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: `Default styles` can be defined where you define your `custom component`, and the rest of the styles can be added based on the `screen props` from it and merged to the styles of the `custom component`.

Comment: Thanks Pritish for the answer